# Unhandled exception on basic db.Query()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know this issue has been covered before, but after several hours of reading other posts, documentation and trials, I am at a loss.  I am new to .Net and C# so I apologize if this is trivial to others.

I am receiving the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories' >from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> WebMatrix.Data.DbProviderFactoryWrapper.CreateConnection(string >connectionString)

On line #9 below: @foreach...

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@{
    var dbconn = Database.OpenConnectionString(@"Provider = .NET Framework 
    Data Provider for OLE DB; Data Source = C:\Users\...dbName.accdb");
    string selStr = "SELECT * From EquipList";
    }

    <table><tr>
    @foreach (dynamic row in dbconn.Query(selStr))
    {<tr>
        <td>@row.recordID
    </tr>}</table>
```

StackTrace:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type             
    'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories' from assembly 'System.Data, 
    Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
at WebMatrix.Data.DbProviderFactoryWrapper.CreateConnection(String 
    connectionString)
at WebMatrix.Data.Database.get_Connection()
at WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen()
at WebMatrix.Data.Database.<QueryInternal>d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at WebMatrix.Data.Database.Query(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
at logCalc.Pages.Test_Page.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in 
    C:\Users\...\Pages\Test.cshtml:line 18
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger
    Notification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView<RenderPageCoreAsync>d__16.
    MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

I have confirmed that the WebMatrix.Data.dll is included and recognized.  Based on the stack trace, it appears that the connection is being established and I cannot get much simpler for the query.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.Data` in your project?

Comment: This doesn't directly solve your problem but, you should not be opening  a connection inside a view. That kind of operation is for the Controller to handle, the view is for how the page should look. The model is what is used to pass data from the controller to the view. Doing this would circumvent your problem though.

Comment: @Shelby115 I originally had the connection string in my model but moved it to the header when I began running into issues in an attempt to simplify. I just moved it back tot he the _layout.Model so that it will be available for all pages. but I am still running into the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  @GabrielLuci, yes each of my .model contain System.Data.

Comment: Several more hours of digging and still no luck.

Comment: What I mean is: In your Solution Explorer, under your project, and under 'References', do you see "System.Data" there?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes,  I have System.Data.dll and System.Data.Common.dll under Microsoft.NETCore.App under SDK. and a few others with varying extensions after the .Data under MIcrosoft.AspNetCore.All

Comment: If you look at the properties of the reference to System.Data, is the version 4.0.0.0?

Comment: It doesn't show a version number. Where the packages listed under NuGet all show version numbers, those under SDK don't show a version. When I go to the actual file under C:\User\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NetCoreApp\2.05 I can inspect the file and see that it is ver. 4.6.26018